# jQuery Tablesorter: How to detect if column is already sorted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

The information in the table is sometimes already sorted, so when the user clicks on the header, the plugin sorts it again in same order, but it looks like nothing is happening. Is there a way to detect if the info is already sorted?

Comment: Usually when you click on a sorted table column, the next click sorts it by descending values if it was ascending before, or ascending if it was descending before the click.

Comment: If the data was originally entered in proper order, say, alphabetically, plugin doesnt know it and tries to sort it again.

Comment: You might want to try programmatically clicking it once then, just to initialize the column that the db returns it ordered by. e.g., `$("#last-name").click()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd set some kind of indicator, i.e. data attribute data-sorted="true" on the column header element and check it before sorting again. Here's some sample jQuery code:

```
$(".column-header").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).data("sorted")) {
        // do sorting
    }
});
```

You can use different values, if you want to alternate sorting direction: asc/desc.