# Is there a way to tell jQuery tablesorter that the table is already sorted?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I've a web app that builds a table from data it receives from an API. These data are a CSV string, which has its rows already sorted by the API using a couple of columns.

Currently, I use the `sortList` option with the same columns, ie, I have tablesorter doing the same sorting, despite this wouldn't be necessary, just to see the order ticks (down/up arrows) next to the column names.

Is there a way to tell tablesorter that the table is already sorted, including the columns? This would only be needed to show those header ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the CSS class of the column(s) that are already sorted.

Here's a demo where the first column already sorted is ascending order. When initializing the table the class `"tablesorter-headerAsc"` is added so that an upward arrow is shown.

```
$("table thead tr:first th:first").addClass("tablesorter-headerAsc");
```

(the JQuery selector `$("table thead tr:first th:first")` selects the first column in the first row of `thead`)

**Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myTable")
    .tablesorter();
  $("table thead tr:first th:first").addClass("tablesorter-headerAsc");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- choose a theme file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bowercdn.net/c/jquery.tablesorter-2.15.2/css/theme.default.css">
<!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>



<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course this trick should be used with caution, as you can never be sure the data is already sorted unless you sort it.

Related question: [jQuery Tablesorter: How to detect if column is already sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286679/jquery-tablesorter-how-to-detect-if-column-is-already-sorted)